# Can't format nvme

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting

I'm trying to install linux over a broken Windows 10 install.

[image]

I've booted on a live USB and tried to remove old partitions and format the disk, but everything I've tried until now failed.

If I try to format the LENOVO parition to NTFS, I'm getting **Input/output error during write on /dev/nvme1n1**.

`fdisk` doesn't work either:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/nvme1n1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.37.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-5, default 5): 4

Partition 4 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy

The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or partx(8).
```

I've tried both partx and partprobe and a restart, still same error.

Or with `dd`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme1n1p4 bs=4096 status=progress
26830630912 bytes (27 GB, 25 GiB) copied, 721 s, 37.2 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/nvme1n1p4': No space left on device
6553601+0 records in
6553600+0 records out
26843545600 bytes (27 GB, 25 GiB) copied, 721.273 s, 37.2 MB/s
```

Seems like I just can't format the disk or delete partitions.

Comment: "The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or partx(8)." Have you tried following these instructions?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I've tried both partx and partprobe and a restart, still the same error

Comment: So please [edit] the question and add that information.

Comment: It sounds like you don't care about anything on the device, so just hose the start rather than the partition. You do not need to do it all, just the first meg or so. Linux will then recreate all the required partitions as it sees fit.

Comment: @Bib That's what I tried first, it fails. I'm getting `failed to commit libparted changes to /dev/nvme0n1` in the installer log

Comment: The last thing to try is a new partition table (Device > create partition table... > choose GPT). If the error persist then the drive failed completely. Replace it.

Comment: `Input/output error during write on /dev/nvme0n1` So the disk is dead ? :sadge:

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I/O errors almost always indicate drive failure. The slot or the controller can fail as well but it's rare, drives fail all the time.

Comment: ANother thing you might try is booting of something like [SytemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/Download/) and see what it makes of the disk ... maybe check `dmesg` output for drive errors.